# Issue with a color picker

Tags: html, css

I work with html markup and have some issue with color picker in mac os. I want to pick up color from picture and get exactly the same color as in the background for div element.

I pickup color by mac color picker, paste it in my css and get a difference in color between sample and background.

[example video](https://youtu.be/n-DCGY-7Qbw)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post an example of your css and the image?

Answer (score 0):

you can use digital color meter that is on mac as well. just make sure that you get the color you want from the picture, double check and make sure that RGB numbers are correct, that should not be a problem, unless you have some code that overwrites it. copy and paste the code snippet here, so i can see if there is anything to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the little square color icon next to the color attribute in your Chrome styles inspector, it will bring up Chrome's color picker. That may be easier to use. Click the eyedropper to select any color from the page. See the image below. [image]

Comment: It's helpful. Works well. Some thing wrong with mac color picker. Thanks!!!